# LaTeX: Replacing the Wallpaper (Wallpaper package)?

Tags: latex

Time to time, I need to change the wallpaper for another one within a document.

And, I noticed that wallpaper keeps the first wallpaper and brings a second wallpaper on the top of the first one (i.e. do not really replace the previous one). Maybe is it a problem with my used command or issue with the package.

I would be pleased if you could help me to let me know how to allow Wallpaper to replace the active wallpaper by another one.

Thank you & best regards

here with my header of latex

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\newcommand{\mywallpaperfixevalue}{}
\renewcommand{\mywallpaperfixevalue}{background-1.pdf}
\renewcommand{\mywallpaperfixevalue}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\mywallpaperfixevalue}{}}
{}
{\CenterWallPaper{1}{\mywallpaperfixevalue}}
\newcommand{\mywallpaperfixe}[1]{{\CenterWallPaper{1}{#1}}}
```

In my tex code, I change the wallpaper with
\mywallpaperfixe}{background-1.pdf}
bla bla ...
\mywallpaperfixe}{background-2.pdf}
bla bla .
...

Comment: Could you visualize (for the community's sake) what you mean by "I noticed that wallpaper keeps the first wallpaper and brings a second wallpaper on the top of the first one"?